# Can I add a message for my retry condition in Karate?

Tags: karate

Is there a possibility in Karate to log a message when the `retry until` condition fails rather than jsut showing "***too many retry attempts***"?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.

You are welcome to contribute code, as Karate is an open source project.